# Remove punctuations in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

```
df['review'].head()
```

```
index  review
0      These flannel wipes are OK, but in my opinion
```

I want to remove punctuations from the column of the dataframe and create a new column.

```
import string
def remove_punctuations(text):
    return text.translate(None, string.punctuation)

df["new_column"] = df['review'].apply(remove_punctuations)
```

Error:

```
    return text.translate(None,string.punctuation)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

I am using python 2.7.

Comment: You want to have a new column with the same string values but without the punctuation? Why?

Comment: @JoeR i am practising sentiment analysis on the data

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Using [Pandas str.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and regex:

```
df["new_column"] = df['review'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
```

Comment: @ Bob Haffner, thank you for this but how would I preserve spaces that previously existed?

Comment: Hi @bob-haffner, I want to remove punctuation (only dot `.`) only after the letter `c` and `p`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 28):

You can build a regex using the `string` module's punctuation list:

```
df['review'].str.replace('[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '')
```

Comment: Use `import string`

Comment: also, I found you need to add `regex=True`, since it defaults to False: `df['review'].str.replace('[{}]'.format(string.punctuation), '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 14):

I solved the problem by looping through the string.punctuation

```
def remove_punctuations(text):
    for punctuation in string.punctuation:
        text = text.replace(punctuation, '')
    return text
```

You can call the function the same way you did and It should work.

```
df["new_column"] = df['review'].apply(remove_punctuations)
```